# Yuanti TC Font on iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I have a design file in Sketch using the standard OSX font Yuanti TC:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206872

However, I can't find it in my Systems Font folder to export it into an iOS app in XCode. Or can't find a way to download it on the web.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Best,
Joey